# javascript add carriage returns to string for readability

Tags: javascript, string

I am wondering if this is possible and if so how, I have a long string and for maintainability and readability purposes I want to put newlines into the code like so:

```
slices += 
    '<div 
        class="'+settings.sliceClass+'"
        style="
            width:' + slicewidth + 'px;
            height:' + sliceheight + 'px;
            left:' + left + 'px;
            top:' + top + 'px;
    "><img src="'+slide.properties.src+'"
        style="
            position: relative;
            left:' + -left + 'px;
            top:' + -top + 'px;
            width:' + Math.round(slide.properties.image.width * slide.properties.scale.width) + 'px;
            height:' + Math.round(slide.properties.image.height * slide.properties.scale.height) + 'px;
    ">
    </img></div>'
);
```

I am not expecting these newlines to appear in the HTML output.

However this returns a `SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF`.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, strings cannot contain unescaped newlines, only line continuations, which means you get the indenting white-space in your output string.  The operative part of the spec is [section 7.8.4](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4):

> ```
> SingleStringCharacter ::
>     SourceCharacter but not single-quote or backslash or LineTerminator
>   | \ EscapeSequence
>   | LineContinuation
> ```

The "but not ... or LineTerminator" part means that strings cannot contain newlines, but the "| LineContinuation" means that \*<LineTerminator>* is OK.  Reading into the string value of *LineContinuation* shows that it does not contribute to the string-value of the quoted string as a whole and does not eat any of the leading whitespace.

You can do

```
slices += 
    ['<div', 
       ' class="', settings.sliceClass, '"',
       ' style="',
     ...
    ].join('');
```

Make each line an element in an array, and join on the empty string.

This will also help avoid confusion between numeric operators and `+` used for string concatenation if you later change the code to do more complex numeric operations than just `-left`.

Comment: Thanks it's nice to see the relevant part of the spec instead of just taking someone's word for it.

Comment: @GeorgeReith, You're welcome.  Fyi, the next version of the language, ES.Next, will have multiline strings as a side-effect of [string templates](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/01/a-critical-review-of-ecmascript-6-quasi-literals/)

Answer (score 4):

Just add a backslash before breaking each line:

```
var str = "sfdsadadadas\
           asdasdasdasdasd\
           sdfsdfsfsd";
```

Keep in mind that the space between each backslash and the (indented) content on the next line **will** be part of the string. That shouldn't be a problem on HTML output, unless you're using preformatted text (like content in `<pre>` tags).

Answer (score 0):

Modified code:.

```
slices +=       '<div'+
            'class="'+settings.sliceClass+'"'+
            .....
```

or you can teke help of array

```
 var temp = [
            '<div',
             'class="'+settings.sliceClass+'"',
            ...

           '</img></div>'
  ];
slices  += temp.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to using `'` (single-quotes) and having `"` (double-quotes) inside those. So I'd try to escape your quotes likes so:

```
var component = "<div class=\"rounded-border\">" +
    "<p>Sample Content here " + dynamicValue + "</p>" +
    "</div>";
```

p.s. Notice the use of the `+` operator, which is very useful and guarantees that the data
is unchanged on the next line, otherwise there might be carriage returns or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
  slices += 
      '<div' +
          'class="'+settings.sliceClass+'"' +
          'style="' +
              'width:' + slicewidth + 'px;' +
              'height:' + sliceheight + 'px;' +
              'left:' + left + 'px;' +
              'top:' + top + 'px;' +
      '">' +
        '<img src="'+slide.properties.src+'"' +
          'style="' +
            'position: relative;' +
              'left:' + -left + 'px;' +
              'top:' + -top + 'px;' +
              'width:' + Math.round(slide.properties.image.width * slide.properties.scale.width) + 'px;' +
              'height:' + Math.round(slide.properties.image.height * slide.properties.scale.height) + 'px;' +
        '" />' +
      '</div>';
```